# ReactNative and Android: 64 bit, Create 64 bit APK without updating react native version?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk, 64-bit

My current `react native version` of the project is `0.52.3`

But now i am i need to create a `64 bit APK`. so i found a great blog about it link below.

https://medium.com/@andriidrozdov/reactnative-and-android-64-bit-new-google-play-market-rules-what-to-do-584b067d6f1a

I can update `Gradle`, but updating `react native version` will cause the `third party libraries` to crash.

Is there anyway i can create a `64 bit APK` without updating the `react native version` ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the app to the version 0.59 which is used to build the apk for 64 bit.

I understand how much the change to files which the `react native version` for using it. It is nightmare :). Now React has the helpful tool for helping you update the app easier. It is `upgrade-helper`.

So Here is step by step:

First check the release note for showing how break change for every version of React

Then using this [upgrade-helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) to upgrade the version.

```
Note that upgrade bit by bit (increase the version slowly). Remove node_modules then reinstall it when you put the new version in package.json.
```

Hoping this will help you.